# Vuetify Chip breaks in Production

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, leaflet

I am using v-chip to act as an info-banner, the v-chip is within a Vue-Leaflet map. The chip is based on this one [here](https://codepen.io/abel-moremi/pen/vYOwybV), I was trying to adapt it to my project. Locally I managed to achieve my goal as shown by the picture below;

[image: working info-chip]

The issue occurs when I deploy my new v-chip feature with firebase hosting, the chip breaks as shown below;

[image: not working chip]

For some reason, it is not showing as it should in production. [Here](https://covid-info-bw.web.app/map) is a link to the current deployed implementation. This is the [Repo](https://github.com/Abel-Moremi/covid-info-bw) and the [code](https://github.com/Abel-Moremi/covid-info-bw/blob/master/src/components/Map-InfoControl.vue) line between lines 72 and 79, below is the code snippert,

```
<div class="text-center">
        <span class="ma-2 v-chip v-chip--outlined v-chip--pill theme--light v-size--default deep-purple accent-4 deep-purple--text text--accent-4">
          <span class="v-chip__content">
            <i aria-hidden="true" class="v-icon notranslate v-icon--left mdi mdi-information-outline theme--light"></i>
            ${placeholder}
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>`
```

**Things I have tried**

- I tried to pick out the differences between [My code pen example](https://codepen.io/abel-moremi/pen/vYOwybV) versus [Deployed app](https://covid-info-bw.web.app/map) by inspecting the classes used by both chips and both chips used the exact same classes, therefore ruling out missing class.
- I have tried copying the CSS directly inspecting the CSS in classes used by the [codePen](https://codepen.io/abel-moremi/pen/vYOwybV) example and implementing it in the local repo just for good measure.

Comment: 99% chance you're not using `v-app` somewhere.

Comment: Why not use `<v-chip>` component ?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I am using it

Comment: @hans I am using javascript to dynamically output

Comment: You are using the class but not the component itself. Try to add the css to your vuetify plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calling a v-chip component, If you want to get all styles, even if you are not calling it in your app, change the vuetify.js in /src/plugins/:

Add the minify styles:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css"; // Add this

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
});
```